# Issues setting up Win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, partitioning

Im trying to reinstall Windows 7 Home Premium on Samsung Ultrabook.

My first try was to create a bootable USB drive with a .iso file. Next I created a new partition with diskpart, set it on ntfs, copied all the files from the USB and installed Windows form there.

Unfortunatly it was a Win 7 Professional version. So I downloaded the correct .iso and tried again.

Again i created a bootable USB, but when I came to chose the partition there were already 4 created. When I tried to intall Windows on the 22gb system partition it made it through the first two steps, rebooted and startet from top. I tried it twice before I wanted to try it with diskpart again, so I opened up diskpart, created a partition but when I could not assign it letter C, which is why i assigned it letter W and tried to copy the files from the USB.

To copy I used

```
xcopy d: w: /e /h /k
```

When it could not copy any file I decided to restart the PC. After turning it on again I got a black screen with a BIOS style windows asking from where I want to boot. Either SATA or USB, non of which works. The screen just goes all black for a few seconds before showing the same window.

Can you spot any mistake I made or help me at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just wipe out all existing partitions before installing Home via the usual install method (don't make partitions, let the installer do it).  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish by copying the installer files from the USB to the HDD to install, just install it from the USB media.

Comment: Like I stated, the installer started from the top by itself all the time when I tried to do it that way.

Comment: To keep you updated: I tried to set up the USB again, but now i don't even see that there is a USB in the BIOS, so I tried to create a new USB drive with Rufus in both, MBR and GPT, non of which is shown in the BIOS. UEFI Boot Spport is activated.